# Find the value of a column over a set of columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling with the way to find the value of a column across other columns of a data.frame. I'd be thankful if anyone could help me. These are a simplified form of my data:

```
library(data.table)

df<-data.table(personid<-c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 201, 202, 203, 301, 302, 401),
       hh_id<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
       fatherid<-c(NA, NA, 101, 101, 101, NA, NA, 201, NA, NA, NA),
       fatherid_1<-c(NA,101, 101, 101, NA, NA, 201, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       fatherid_2<-c(101, 101, 101, NA, NA, 201, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       fatherid_3<-c(101, 101, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       fatherid_4<-c(101, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       fatherid_5<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

(the real one is 185000 rows and has up to 17 variables such as `fatherid_1`, `fatherid_2`... `fatherid_17`)

What I'm trying to do is to create a variable that checks whether the value of variable `personid` of a given row is the same as any of the values of variables `fatherid_1` to `fatherid_5` in the same row. For the given data, the outcome should be:

```
df$result <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

but I need something to do it automatically, over 17 columns such as `fatherid_1`, and a lot of rows

In case you want to understand the sense of my calculations, I'm trying to build household grids without using only information in the same row

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I needed. Thank you everybody! However,  now I am wondering if there is any way of doing it without the duplicated "fatherid_1, 2, 3" variables, i.e: by "looking for the value" of personid among the different "fatherid" values of members of the same household (hh_id) ¿Would it be possible? Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you ask a new question with this new topic.

Answer (score 3):

**Two tidyverse solutions:**

1-) You can use dplyr's new `if_any()`, `.==` and tidyr's `replace_na()`. `if_any()` obviates the need for either `rowwise()` or `reduce()`/ `Reduce()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df%>%mutate(result=replace_na(if_any(matches('fatherid'), ~.==personid), 0))
```

2-) In a `rowwise()` operation, you can apply a function to check the condition for all the selected columns with `map()`, `c_across()` and `%in%`, which generates a logical vector. This can then be collapsed/`reduce()`d in the same call.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(result=as.integer(reduce(map(c_across(fatherid_1:fatherid_5), ~. %in% personid), `|`)))
```

Or with pipes, for clarity:

```
#option 1
df%>%rowwise()%>%
        mutate(result=map(c_across(fatherid_1:fatherid_5), ~. %in% personid)%>%
                       reduce(`|`)%>%
                       as.integer())
#option 2
df%>%rowwise()%>%
        mutate(result=map_int(c_across(fatherid_1:fatherid_5), ~. %in% personid)%>%
                       reduce(max))

    personid hh_id fatherid fatherid_1 fatherid_2 fatherid_3 fatherid_4 fatherid_5 result
 1:      101     1       NA         NA        101        101        101         NA      1
 2:      102     1       NA        101        101        101         NA         NA      0
 3:      103     1      101        101        101         NA         NA         NA      0
 4:      104     1      101        101         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 5:      105     1      101         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 6:      201     2       NA         NA        201         NA         NA         NA      1
 7:      202     2       NA        201         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 8:      203     2      201         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 9:      301     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
10:      302     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
11:      401     4       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
```

Comment: Brilliant solution my friend.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the following solution with `pmap` from `purrr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(result = pmap_dbl(., ~ {x <- c(...)[-c(1, 2)]; 
  if_else(all(x[!is.na(x)] != c(...)[1]) | all(is.na(x)), 0, 1)}))


    personid hh_id fatherid fatherid_1 fatherid_2 fatherid_3 fatherid_4 fatherid_5 result
 1:      101     1       NA         NA        101        101        101         NA      1
 2:      102     1       NA        101        101        101         NA         NA      0
 3:      103     1      101        101        101         NA         NA         NA      0
 4:      104     1      101        101         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 5:      105     1      101         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 6:      201     2       NA         NA        201         NA         NA         NA      1
 7:      202     2       NA        201         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 8:      203     2      201         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 9:      301     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
10:      302     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
11:      401     4       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
```

Comment: :) master of `pmap`

Comment: hahaha, Thank you master of `accumulate` and `reduce`.

Comment: Hahahahah, Master of pmap indeed

Comment: @GuedesBF , Because normally I arrive late at every question, `pmap` is usually the only option that is left so I got a reputation as this lol. But I can't deny I really like `purrr`. You are excellent at using `purrr` I noticed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `rowwise` then this can also be an alternative

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(personid) %>%
  mutate(res = sum(cur_group() %in% cur_data()))

# A tibble: 11 x 9
# Groups:   personid [11]
   personid hh_id fatherid fatherid_1 fatherid_2 fatherid_3 fatherid_4 fatherid_5   res
      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl>      <int>
 1      101     1       NA         NA        101        101        101 NA             1
 2      102     1       NA        101        101        101         NA NA             0
 3      103     1      101        101        101         NA         NA NA             0
 4      104     1      101        101         NA         NA         NA NA             0
 5      105     1      101         NA         NA         NA         NA NA             0
 6      201     2       NA         NA        201         NA         NA NA             1
 7      202     2       NA        201         NA         NA         NA NA             0
 8      203     2      201         NA         NA         NA         NA NA             0
 9      301     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA NA             0
10      302     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA NA             0
11      401     4       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA NA             0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you want to be safe excluding `hh_id` you could use

```
df %>% group_by(personid) %>%
  mutate(res = sum(cur_group() %in% cur_data()[-1]))
```

Comment: Nice rowwise-less solution. We must acknowledge, however, that, in this case, grouping by rows(rowwise()) is not much different from grouping by personid, since there is likely one unique personid per row.

Answer (score 2):

A way to solve it in *base* using `==` to make the comparison and test if the `rowSums` `>0`:

```
+(rowSums(df[[1]] == df[,3:8], na.rm=TRUE) > 0)
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or using `any` with `apply`.

```
+apply(df[[1]] == df[,3:8], 1, any, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or the same but using pipes:

```
(df[[1]] == df[,3:8]) |> rowSums(na.rm=TRUE) |> (`>`)(0) |> as.integer()

(df[[1]] == df[,3:8]) |> apply(1, any, na.rm=TRUE) |> as.integer()
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP's dataset is a `data.table` object.  We can use `data.table` methods.  Loop over the 'fatherid' columns, check if the 'personid' is equal to the column value, and `Reduce` to a single vector

```
library(data.table)
df[, result  := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
      x == personid & !is.na(x)))), .SDcols = patterns('fatherid')]
```

-output

```
df
    personid hh_id fatherid fatherid_1 fatherid_2 fatherid_3 fatherid_4 fatherid_5 result
 1:      101     1       NA         NA        101        101        101         NA      1
 2:      102     1       NA        101        101        101         NA         NA      0
 3:      103     1      101        101        101         NA         NA         NA      0
 4:      104     1      101        101         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 5:      105     1      101         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 6:      201     2       NA         NA        201         NA         NA         NA      1
 7:      202     2       NA        201         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 8:      203     2      201         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
 9:      301     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
10:      302     3       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
11:      401     4       NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA      0
```