# R, dplyr: how to change the value in one column to NA based on NA values in other columns (using OR operator)

Tags: r, tidyverse, na, dplyr

This problem is hard to express in a title line, but it is a different question than the usual "how do I change the value in one column based on a value in another column." There are two wrinkles I haven't seen dealt with elsewhere: 1) I'm dealing with NAs, not values, 2) I'm dealing with a condition involving an OR relationship between multiple columns, i.e., if `V01` is NA **or** `V02` is NA, then make var `foo` (which already exists with no NAs) NA for that row.

Here's a small tibble to illustrate:

```
tbl <- tibble(
  V01 = 10:15,
  V02 = 1:6,
  V03 = V02 * 2,
  foo = V03 * 2
)
# sprinkle around some NAs
tbl[1,2] = NA
tbl[4,1] = NA
tbl[4,2] = NA
tbl[6,1:3] = NA
```

that produces this table:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2     4
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    16
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    24
```

Ultimately I want to produce this kind of logic for each row in `tbl`:

```
if (V01 == NA | V02 == NA | V03 == NA) {foo = NA}
```

I started by trying to use `mutate`to change `foo` to NA based on one column, like this:

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(
  foo = case_when(V01 == NA ~ NA)
  )
```

But even in this simple case, mutate changed every value of `foo` to NA:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03 foo  
  <int> <int> <dbl> <lgl>
1    10    NA     2 NA   
2    11     2     4 NA   
3    12     3     6 NA   
4    NA    NA     8 NA   
5    14     5    10 NA   
6    NA    NA    NA NA
```

I thought maybe I needed a `rowwise` in there, but that didn't change the result.

Then I thought maybe it's because NAs are weird, so let's try something simpler: change `foo` to -1 if `V01` is NA:

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(
  foo = case_when(V01 == NA ~ -1)
  )
```

But that produced the same result, all values of `foo` changed to NA (and the value of `foo` in row 4 did not change to -1 either).

Then I decided to do something even simpler. Leave the NAs out of the picture. If `V01` is 10 (as in the first row only), change the `foo` value in that row to -1. So:

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(
  foo = case_when(V01 == 10 ~ -1)
  )
```

And that produced this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2    -1
2    11     2     4    NA
3    12     3     6    NA
4    NA    NA     8    NA
5    14     5    10    NA
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

So why is `mutate` changing values in rows that don't meet the specified condition in the `mutate` statement?

Note I haven't even gotten to the OR condition yet. For what it's worth, this is the result I want to get:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2    NA
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    NA
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I wasn't able to use the dplyr `na_if` function because it only takes a value to replace with NA, not a condition.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can also use this beside all the very good answers you received:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tbl %>%
  mutate(foo = pmap_dbl(.,  ~ c(c(...)[length(tbl)], NA)[any(is.na(c(...)[-length(tbl)])) + 1]))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2    NA
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    NA
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Or this one also can be used:

```
tbl %>%
  mutate(foo = pmap_dbl(., ~ ifelse(any(is.na(c(...)[-length(tbl)])), NA, ..4)))
```

Comment: why coerce `foo` to character here?

Comment: @GuedesBF Thank you very much, it was a mistake. Got it wrong from the beginning but I think it's fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Base R strategy

```
tbl$foo <- tbl$foo * as.logical(rowSums(tbl))

tbl
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2    NA
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    NA
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

---

using `cur_data()`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

tbl %>% mutate(foo = pmin(foo, rowSums(cur_data())))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>     V01   V02   V03   foo
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    NA     2    NA
#> 2    11     2     4     8
#> 3    12     3     6    12
#> 4    NA    NA     8    NA
#> 5    14     5    10    20
#> 6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Note: Assuming columns don't have negative values

---

If there are negative values, you may do

```
tbl %>% mutate(foo = foo * as.logical(rowSums(cur_data())))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2    NA
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    NA
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: You put `cur_data()` on the map hahaha.

Comment: `* as.logical(rowSums)` is a really nice hack

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of options -

1. Using `rowSums` -

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
  mutate(foo = replace(foo, rowSums(is.na(select(., starts_with('V')))) > 0, NA))

#    V01   V02   V03   foo
#  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    10    NA     2    NA
#2    11     2     4     8
#3    12     3     6    12
#4    NA    NA     8    NA
#5    14     5    10    20
#6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

2. Using `rowwise` -

```
tbl %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(foo = if(any(is.na(c_across(starts_with('V'))))) NA else foo)
```

Both of this replace `foo` with `NA` if there is a `NA` value in any of the columns starting with `V`.

---

As far as this code is concerned

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(foo = case_when(V01 == 10 ~ -1))
```

`case_when` by default returns `NA` if no condition is satisfied. To get the same value back you can do

```
tbl %>% 
  mutate(foo = case_when(V01 == 10 ~ -1, 
                        TRUE ~ foo))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Main solution**

You can use `if_any()` and `is.na`to check rowwise for any NAs. `if_any()` obviates the need for either `rowwise()` or `reduce()`/ `Reduce()`, which makes it ideal for row-wise logical opperations.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl%>%mutate(foo=replace(foo, if_any(matches("V\\d{2}"), is.na), NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2    NA
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    NA
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

**Secondary but possibly very fast solution with `map()` and `reduce()`:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tbl%>%mutate(foo=ifelse(reduce(map(across(matches("V\\d{2}")), is.na), `|`), NA, foo))
```

`if_any()` is a new and very nice and cleaner alternative to the usual approaches to logical rowwise opperations with `rowSums(condition)` / `pmap()` +`<-c(...)` / `rowwise()`+`c_across()` / `map()`+`Reduce()` / `apply(margin=1)`.

For interesting yet slightly different uses of this approach, see my answers in:
[R - Remove rows from dataframe that contain only zeros in numeric columns, base R and pipe-friendly methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754119/r-remove-rows-from-dataframe-that-contain-only-zeros-in-numeric-columns-base/67754388#67754388) and
[Find the value of a column over a set of columns in a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874735/find-the-value-of-a-column-over-a-set-of-columns-in-a-data-frame-in-r/67874916#67874916)

**EDIT**

There is an even cleaner solution with `if_all()`:

```
tbl%>%mutate(foo=foo*if_all(everything()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
    V01 = 10:15,
    V02 = 1:6,
    V03 = V02 * 2,
    foo = V03 * 2
)
# sprinkle around some NAs
tbl[1,2] = NA
tbl[4,1] = NA
tbl[4,2] = NA
tbl[6,1:3] = NA

#alternative faster way

criteria <- apply(tbl[, -4], 1, \(.x) .x) %>%
              as.data.frame() %>%
              map_lgl(~ any(is.na(.x))) 

mutate(tbl,foo = ifelse(criteria, NA, foo))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>     V01   V02   V03   foo
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    NA     2    NA
#> 2    11     2     4     8
#> 3    12     3     6    12
#> 4    NA    NA     8    NA
#> 5    14     5    10    20
#> 6    NA    NA    NA    NA

tbl %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(foo = ifelse(any(is.na(c_across(matches('[0-9]$')))), NA, foo))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     V01   V02   V03   foo
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    NA     2    NA
#> 2    11     2     4     8
#> 3    12     3     6    12
#> 4    NA    NA     8    NA
#> 5    14     5    10    20
#> 6    NA    NA    NA    NA


#if foo has no NA's
tbl %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(foo = ifelse(any(is.na(c_across(everything()))), NA, foo))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     V01   V02   V03   foo
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    NA     2    NA
#> 2    11     2     4     8
#> 3    12     3     6    12
#> 4    NA    NA     8    NA
#> 5    14     5    10    20
#> 6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Foo column can also be created while looking for NA's

```r
library(tidyverse)
#no foo column
tbl_no_foo <- tibble(
    V01 = 10:15,
    V02 = 1:6,
    V03 = V02 * 2
)
# sprinkle around some NAs
tbl_no_foo[1,2] = NA
tbl_no_foo[4,1] = NA
tbl_no_foo[4,2] = NA
tbl_no_foo[6,1:3] = NA


tbl_no_foo %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(foo = ifelse(any(is.na(c_across(matches('[0-9]$')))), NA, V03 * 2))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     V01   V02   V03   foo
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    NA     2    NA
#> 2    11     2     4     8
#> 3    12     3     6    12
#> 4    NA    NA     8    NA
#> 5    14     5    10    20
#> 6    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all these alternative solutions. What works best for me is a variation on the `reduce()`and `map()` solution, plugging in the actual list variables to check, rather than doing a `match`.

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(
  foo=ifelse(reduce(map(across(c("V01", "V02", "V03")), is.na), `|`), NA, foo)
  )
```

This is easiest since I'm working with an Election Studies dataset, which has 1300 variables, all starting with "V". Where this problem came from, if anyone is interested, is a byproduct of using the R `psych` package to build psychometric scales from some sets of variables, such as 4 questions that measure 'anti-govt' attitudes. `Psych` makes it very easy to create and test the reliability of a scale, but its default behavior is to give the scale variable a value even if all the input variables are NA. Given that the dataset has over 8,000 cases, I can afford the 10% or so decline in cases that results from assigning NA to the scale variable if any of the input variables are NA. A useful variant of this solution makes it easy to assign NA to the scale variable only if **all** the input variables are NA. Just change the `|` operator to an `&`. So this:

```
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(
  foo=ifelse(reduce(map(across(c("V01", "V02", "V03")), is.na), `&`), NA, foo)
```

produces this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    V01   V02   V03   foo
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    NA     2     4
2    11     2     4     8
3    12     3     6    12
4    NA    NA     8    16
5    14     5    10    20
6    NA    NA    NA    NA
  )
```

Another smaller side issue is the use of base R `ifelse()` vs dplyr `if_else()`. The latter doesn't work here because it requires both alternatives to be of the same type. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse) is useful on the differences between the 2 functions.

Comment: Glad I could help with the solution